# How to prevent 'hyperopt' from integrating failed model outcomes into parameter updating?

Tags: python, neural-network, hyperopt

Using the hyperopt library in python, I want to optimize parameters of a neural network. Occasionally, the chosen parameter combinations lead to an unstable model, causing the model building procedure to crash.

Now, I have created a try/except exception handler that prevents the entire hyperparameter optimization process to stop. The problem I face, is that the hyperopt updating still integrates the (arbitrarily chosen) loss outcome of the failed model to inform the subsequent parameter choices. I want hyperopt to ignore the failed models. My objective function is the following:

```
def objective_fn_for_ann_hyperopt(params, nfolds=5):

     config.ITERATION += 1
     try:
            model = h2o.estimators.H2ODeepLearningEstimator(
            activation='rectifier_with_dropout',
            rho=params['rho'],
            epsilon=params['epsilon'],
            max_w2=10.,
            epochs=params['epochs'],
            hidden=hidden,
            nfolds=nfolds,
            hidden_dropout_ratios=hidden_dropout_ratios,
            input_dropout_ratio=params['input_dropout_ratio'],
            l2=params['l2'],
            l1=1e-5,
            distribution=params['distribution'],
            stopping_metric='mse',
            stopping_tolerance=0.05,
            stopping_rounds=15,

            keep_cross_validation_predictions=True,
            fold_assignment="Modulo",

        )

            model.train(config.x, config.y, training_frame=config.train,
                        validation_frame=config.test)


            run_time = timer() - start

            loss = model._model_json['output']['cross_validation_metrics_summary'].as_data_frame(
            ).iloc[5]['mean']


            success = STATUS_OK #'ok'
        except:

            success = STATUS_FAIL  #'fail'              
            loss = 0 #arbitrary number
            run_time = timer() - start


        return {'loss': loss, 'params': params, 'iteration': config.ITERATION,

                'train_time': run_time, 'status': success}
```

How can I communicate to the hyperopt updater, not to integrate the information of failed models?

Comment: please take a look at this answer, it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933103/how-can-i-grid-search-different-values-for-my-keras-model-in-python/54933367#54933367

Comment: thx. the linked comment describes the execution in general. it does not necessarily cover what happens, when the model building fails. STATUS_OK is simply imported and never altered.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be addressed by either omitting the loss key from the returned dictionary, or by setting it equal to None.

It's discussed in this pull request- https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/pull/176